# JS PopUp windows from different sources

Tags: javascript, php

I need make a simple JS popup to view specific content of each link (team stats). For that I've got basic HTML set up which should popup mentioned content.

```
   <!-- Start Team-Players -->
      <div class="team-players">
        <div class="player-profile">
          <img data-js="open" src="img/team-ico/team-srsne.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail">
          <span class="number">#1</span>
          <span class="name">HK Sršňe Košice</span>
        </div>            
        <div class="player-profile">
          <img data-js="open" src="img/team-ico/team-kvp.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail">
          <span class="number">#2</span>
          <span class="name">HK KVP Represent</span>
        </div>
        <div class="player-profile">
          <img data-js="open" src="img/team-ico/team-warriors.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail" >
          <span class="number">#3</span>
          <span class="name">HK Spartan Warriors</span>
        </div>
```

etc...

at the end there is popup opening code:

```
<div class="container">
<button data-js="open">Open popup</button>
```

```
<div class="popup">
<h2>$team_name (team name, which was selected for links above should be displayed)</h2>
<button name="close">Close popup</button>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function popupOpenClose(popup) {

/* Add div inside popup for layout if one doesn't exist */
if ($(".wrapper").length == 0){
    $(popup).wrapInner("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
}

/* Open popup */


$(popup).show().this;


/* Close popup if user clicks on background */
$(popup).click(function(e) {
    if ( e.target == this ) {
        if ($(popup).is(':visible')) {
            $(popup).hide();
        }
    }
});

/* Close popup and remove errors if user clicks on cancel or close buttons */
$(popup).find("button[name=close]").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".formElementError").is(':visible')) {
        $(".formElementError").remove();
    }
    $(popup).hide();
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("[data-js=open]").on("click", function() {
    popupOpenClose($(".popup"));
  });
});
```

Could someone help me and advise how can I sort those links to open popup window related to each link? Maybe sort it with some ID or so?

Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 solutions:

1. in html create hidden popups for all teams with id="popup-team-1", and in your link add additional attribute `<a data-id="1"..` , in javascript do something like this:

`var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
 $("#popup-team-"+id).show();`

2. load content of popup from server

   ```
   $.get(url).done(function (content) {
        $(".popup").html(content).show();
   })
   ```

Comment: But how could I sort an output? data-id attribute needs to be included also?

  <div class="container" data-id="1">
<button data-js="open">Open popup</button>